# How to Speed up the json fetching in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, ios6

I want to speed up the fetching the JSON data.In android we have Robospice Framework,like that any framework available in iOS. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to speed up? Isn't NSJSONSerialization fast enough? Is it the connection that's causing performance problems?

Comment: Thanks for Replying..I dont know exactly,i will explain one scenario..For example first time if we fetch data from server,after some time we loss connection.At that time previous data we have to store in any temporary memory(ex: cache).so we will show data from that cache(Previous data)..in android for this type of situation they are using Robospice Framework..Hope you understand..Thanks in advance..pls guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by speed up fetching JSON? Speed up your coding time, or the actual request?
There's not a lot you can do to speed up the request, but there are multiple libraries available to help you code the fetching.

The one you'll see a lot of people mention and talk about is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: Thanks for giving Reply.Actually Android people are using robospice network to speed up the Json fetching.is it avalilablein ios?..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Well the speed that you fetch the JSON is governed by your connection speed so there's not a lot you can do. But iOS probably does the best it can to improve performance, otherwise try `AFNetworking`

Comment: Thank you fr gvng reply.